# append uiImage to uiImageArray

Tags: swiftui, uiimage

I want to append an image or oldimageArray to newimageArray, and display all the images, but I am getting an error when i building code:
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pvmsD.png)
"No exact matches in reference to static method 'buildExpression'" in uiImageArray.append(uiImage)

this is my code:

```
struct ShowImageView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject private var viewController: ViewController
    @State private var uiImageArray: [UIImage] = []
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 16), count: 3), spacing: 16) {
                ForEach(uiImageArray, id: \.self) { uiImage in
                    ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                        Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                            .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                            .clipShape(Rectangle())
                            .cornerRadius(10)
                    }
                    Button(action: {
                        if let index = uiImageArray.firstIndex(of: uiImage) {
                            uiImageArray.remove(at: index)
                        }
                    }) {
                        Image(systemName: "x.circle")
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                            .background(Color.white)
                            .clipShape(Circle())
                            .padding(5)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    ForEach(cardViewModel.cardRecordPhotos) { record in
                        if let uiImage = UIImage(data: record.avatar) {
                            uiImageArray.append(uiImage)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
            Button(action: {
                viewController.showImagePicker(maxNum: 5)
            }) {
                Image(systemName: "plus")
                    .font(.system(size: 40, weight: .bold))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
            .onChange(of: viewController.selectedImages) { newValue in
                uiImageArray.append(newValue)
            }
            
            ForEach(viewController.selectedImages, id: \.self) { uiImage in
                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
                    .clipShape(Rectangle())
                    .cornerRadius(10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And cardRecordPhotos is defined as follows：

struct PhotoData: Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let avatar: Data
}

class CardViewModel: ObservableObject {
@Published var cardRecordPhotos: [PhotoData] = []

How to modify the code？

Comment: Your error is because you are using `ForEach` which is in essence a `View` construct that must return a View. It is not the "normal" for loop that you want. So in `.onAppear` try using `for record in cardViewModel.cardRecordPhotos {...}`.

Comment: Thank you, the problem solved successfully